# Does clobbering a backbone view destroy it?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

`activeView = new WhateverView({example:example})`

This model is active, doing stuff w/e

Then I do...

`activeView = new WhateverView({example:otherExample})`

Does this sufficently destroy the old instance of the model or do I need to unbind/delete to prevent a zombie instance?

Comment: Why would instantiating a class have any effect on prior instances of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does create a zombie instance.

You need to unbind your first instance.

Check this post out for more details. http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Comment: You dont need to delete the instance. All you have to do is to unbind the events you have added to a model, collection or element, cause the function you have know live in the  context of the event listener of the collection/model/element and not in the context of your view.